Is it possible to sync data in background React Native?
I'm struggling with a functionality in my app since few weeks.
I will explain my project ; I have a react native app, that connect multiples user. A user can create an event, like a meeting, and the other user get a notification. The event is added in the native calendar of the user who created the meeting (let's call him user 1), and I want to add it also in the user who is invited to the meeting (let's call him user 2). My functionality to sync events in the native calendar for the user 2 is working fine, when the user open the app, or the app state change. But I want to sync the native calendar of user 2 even if he not open the app, like in background.
So for that, I've two solution in my mind. The best one is the notifications. So when the user 1 create a meeting, user 2 always get a notification and my idea is when the notification is shown, I can sync the calendar. So for notifications, I use firebase, and the notifications are shown in background, but my code is not executed. The problem is that I've some error with my code running background messages. My error say that I run multiple HeadlessTask with the id ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask. I don't know why I get this error, but i still have the background notification, but not with the console.log(). So I give up this idea with the notifications.
Here is my code to register background notifications :
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { API_KEY, PROJECT_ID, STORAGE_BUCKET, MESSAGING_SENDER_ID, APP_ID } from '@env';

import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import { syncCalendarEventId } from '../utils/calendarSync';

const register = async () => {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: `${API_KEY}`,
      projectId: `${PROJECT_ID}`,
      storageBucket: `${STORAGE_BUCKET}`,
      messagingSenderId: `${MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}`,
      appId: `${APP_ID}`,
      // databaseURL: '...',
      // authDomain: '...',
    };

    firebase
    .initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    .then(() => {
        registerBackgroundMessage();
    })
    .catch(error => {
    });
};

export async function initializeNotifications() {
    await register();

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        register();
    } else {
        registerBackgroundMessage();
    }
}

// Request user permission for notifications
export async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
        const token = await messaging().getToken();
        return token;
    }
}

// Register background handler
const registerBackgroundMessage = () => {
    console.log("bg")
    if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
        messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log('Notification reçue en fond ! : ', remoteMessage);
            if(remoteMessage.data && remoteMessage.data.sync_required == 1){
                syncCalendarEventId();
            }
        });
    } else if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
        const headlessNotificationHandler = async (remoteMessage) => {
            console.log('Notification reçue en fond ! : ', remoteMessage);
            // Ajoutez ici toute logique que vous souhaitez traiter en arrière-plan
        };
        
        // Enregistrez la tâche headless
        AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
            'ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask', 
            () => headlessNotificationHandler
        );
    }
};

The second idea I get (but the worst I think) is to try syncing the event every 30 minutes or every hour. I try to do that with the react-native-background-fetch library, but still not working. I don't know why, but my code is not running event after 20 or 25 minutes. Here is my code for this library :
  useEffect(() => {
    const configureBackgroundFetch = async () => {
      console.log("configure bg");
      BackgroundFetch.configure(
        {
          minimumFetchInterval: 15,
          stopOnTerminate: false,
          startOnBoot: true,
        },
        async (taskId) => {
          console.log("sync")
          syncCalendarEventId();
          console.log(`Tâche de fetch avec ID ${taskId} exécutée`);
          BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('Erreur de configuration BackgroundFetch:', error);
        }
      );
      
      console.log("fetch start");
      BackgroundFetch.start();
      console.log("fetch started");
    };

    configureBackgroundFetch();

  }, []);

For information, the useEffect is in my App.js file. And for the background fetch library, I already install it properly I think.

I checked background fetch, background precessing, and background notifications in xcode
I updated the file Info.plist with the code below :

    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
    </array>

So my question is : Is it possible to create a function like a calendar sync in background, or I just let the sync when the user opens my app ?
Thank you for your precious help :)

Let me break down the feasible approaches and provide some recommendations:
// NotificationService.js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { syncCalendarEventId } from './calendarSync';

class NotificationService {
  async initialize() {
    // Request permissions
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (!enabled) {
      console.log('User notification permissions denied');
      return false;
    }

    // Get FCM token
    const token = await messaging().getToken();
    console.log('FCM Token:', token);

    // Register background handler
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(this.handleBackgroundMessage);
    } else {
      // For Android, we only need to register the task once
      if (!AppRegistry.getRunnable('ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask')) {
        AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
          'ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask',
          () => this.handleBackgroundMessage
        );
      }
    }

    // Register foreground handler
    messaging().onMessage(this.handleForegroundMessage);

    return true;
  }

  handleBackgroundMessage = async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log('Background Message received:', remoteMessage);
    
    try {
      if (remoteMessage.data?.sync_required === '1') {
        await syncCalendarEventId();
        console.log('Calendar sync completed in background');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in background sync:', error);
    }
  }

  handleForegroundMessage = async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log('Foreground Message received:', remoteMessage);
    
    try {
      if (remoteMessage.data?.sync_required === '1') {
        await syncCalendarEventId();
        console.log('Calendar sync completed in foreground');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in foreground sync:', error);
    }
  }
}

export default new NotificationService();

// App.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import BackgroundFetch from 'react-native-background-fetch';
import NotificationService from './NotificationService';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const setupBackgroundTasks = async () => {
      // Initialize notifications
      await NotificationService.initialize();

      // Configure background fetch as a fallback
      BackgroundFetch.configure({
        minimumFetchInterval: 15, // 15 minutes minimum
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        startOnBoot: true,
        enableHeadless: true,
        forceAlarmManager: true, // Use AlarmManager for more reliable scheduling on Android
      }, async (taskId) => {
        console.log('[BackgroundFetch] Task received:', taskId);
        try {
          await syncCalendarEventId();
          console.log('[BackgroundFetch] Calendar sync completed');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('[BackgroundFetch] Sync error:', error);
        }
        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
      }, (error) => {
        console.error('[BackgroundFetch] Configure error:', error);
      });

      // Start background fetch
      const status = await BackgroundFetch.status();
      console.log('[BackgroundFetch] status:', status);
      
      if (status !== BackgroundFetch.STATUS_RESTRICTED) {
        await BackgroundFetch.start();
      }
    };

    setupBackgroundTasks();

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      BackgroundFetch.stop();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    // Your app components
  );
};

export default App;

Here's my analysis of your situation and recommendations:
Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Approach

This is indeed the best approach for real-time syncing
Your error about multiple HeadlessTask registrations occurs because the registration might be happening multiple times
In the provided solution, I've separated the notification logic into a service class and ensured single registration
The background handler is properly structured for both iOS and Android

Background Fetch Approach

This should be used as a fallback mechanism, not the primary sync method
iOS and Android have strict limitations on background task frequency
The provided solution includes better error handling and logging
Added forceAlarmManager: true for more reliable Android scheduling

Best Practices Implementation

Use both approaches in combination:



FCM as primary method for immediate syncs




Background fetch as a fallback to catch any missed updates


Proper error handling and logging for debugging

Separated concerns into different files for better maintenance


Recommendations for Your Specific Case

Implement the provided NotificationService class
Keep background fetch interval at 15 minutes minimum to respect battery life
Add proper error handling in your syncCalendarEventId function
Consider adding a queue system for failed syncs
Add timestamp checking to avoid duplicate calendar entries


Hello, thank you for your solution, but I still have the same issue about notifications in background. They shows up, but the console log not shows in the console and the event is not synced in the calendar... I don't know why, but I'm struggling with this issue. And also, for the background fetch, I got a status of 2, which means is denied. I checked in background refresh app and my app is active, so I don't know why it is denied...
